# 2-dimensional array assignment: "reference to an object was not set for an instance of the object"

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I'm getting "reference to an object was not set for an instance of the object" run-time error with the suggestion: "Use the new keyword to create an object instance.
But I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

There is my code:

```
int numListas = 10;    
x = 15;
int[][] listas;
listas = new int[numListas][];
Random random = new Random(); // generate random number
for (idx = 0; idx < numListas; idx++)
{
 int idx_el;
 for (idx_el = 0; idx_el < x ; idx_el++)
 {
  listas[idx][idx_el] = random.Next(0,100);
 }
}
```

Comment: You don't have a 2D array, you have an array of arrays. Which is a different thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
int[][] listas;
```

declares a variable which is a reference to an *array of arrays*.

This line:

```
listas = new int[numListas][];
```

initializes the variable to refer to an array of `numListas` array references... but each of those "subarray" references is null to start with. You need to initialize each "subarray", probably in your outer loop:

```
for (idx = 0; idx < numListas; idx++)
{
    listas[idx] = new int[x];
    ...
}
```

Note that an alternative is to use a *rectangular array* instead of an array of arrays:

```
int[,] listas = new int[numListas, x];
...

// In your loop
listas[idx, idx_el] = random.Next(0, 100);
```

As an aside, code generally reads more clearly when you declare and initialize variables together, rather than declaring them earlier and then initializing them later. Also, underscores in C# variable names aren't terribly idiomatic, and the overall variable names aren't terribly clear. I'd write your code as:

```
// Consider declaring these as constants outside the method
int rowCount = 10;
int columnCount = 15;

int[][] values = new int[rowCount];
Random random = new Random();
for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
{
    values[row] = new int[columnCount];
    for (int column = 0; column < columnCount; column++)
    {
        values[row][column] = random.Next(100);
    }
}
```

You should also consider initializing a single `Random` instance outside the method and passing it in - see my [article on `Random`](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You don't set a dimension for the second dimension 
`listas = new int[numListas][];`.

As you are using `x` as the limit of your loop, use that as dimension:

```
for (idx = 0; idx < numListas; idx++)
{
 int idx_el;
 listas[idx] = new int[x]; // initialize the second dimension
 for (idx_el = 0; idx_el < x ; idx_el++)
 {
  listas[idx][idx_el] = random.Next(0,100);
 }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a rectangular array at the beginning:

```
int[,] listas = new int[numListas,x];
```

Comment: You might be confusing the jagged array with a 2D array. The code you pasted won’t compile.

Comment: That's not valid C# - you can't create a jagged array like that. You can create a *rectangular* array using `new int[10, 5]`, but not a jagged array. You need to explicitly loop.

Comment: Yes, I realized that as well.

Comment: You'd need to change the array declaration as well... and the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize each inner array within your jagged array:

```
int numListas = 10;    
x = 15;
int[][] listas;
listas = new int[numListas][];
Random random = new Random(); // generate random number
for (idx = 0; idx < numListas; idx++)
{
 listas[idx] = new int[x];   // initialize inner array
 int idx_el;
 for (idx_el = 0; idx_el < x ; idx_el++)
 {
  listas[idx][idx_el] = random.Next(0,100);
 }
}
```

Alternatively, you may use a two-dimensional array:

```
int numListas = 10;    
x = 15;
int[,] listas;
listas = new int[numListas,x];   // 2D array
Random random = new Random(); // generate random number
for (idx = 0; idx < numListas; idx++)
{
 int idx_el;
 for (idx_el = 0; idx_el < x ; idx_el++)
 {
  listas[idx,idx_el] = random.Next(0,100);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to initialize the second dimension of the array?

```
listas = new int[numListas][x];
            initialize this ^
```